# findHomography returns negative values

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, homography

To find the homography between 2 pictures I've used OpenCV 2.4.8, java version but got the following problem:

I can find more than 2 thousands matches but the findHomography function returns some negative values. The statement for the homography is the following:

```
Mat homography = Calib3d.findHomography(goodReferencePoints, goodScenePoints);
```

And as you can see in my terminal, the homography returns these negative values:

> H= [0.0728467050846091, -1.778341899752422, 523.4269328629535;
>   0.05293440263461851, -1.283649810597391, 377.7784434651413;
>   0.0001384401936905583, -0.003397194330027168, 1]

The 1 at the end seems to me to be correct, but these is the only value in these matrix that it is correct :/

Any idea why? How can I get a better Matrix?

Thank you in advance

My code:

```
    private void findCorners() {

    Mat img_matches = new Mat();

    List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
    if (matchesList.size() < 4) {
        // There are too few matches to find the homography.
        System.err.println("There are too few matches to find the homography.");
        return;
    }

    List<KeyPoint> object_keypoints_list = object_keypoints.toList();
    List<KeyPoint> scene_keypoints_list = scene_keypoints.toList();
    this.object_good_keypoints = new ArrayList<KeyPoint>();
    this.scene_good_keypoints = new ArrayList<KeyPoint>();

    // Calculate the max and min distances between keypoints.
    double maxDist = 0.0;
    double minDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(DMatch match : matchesList) {
        double dist = match.distance;
        if (dist < minDist) {
            minDist = dist;
        }
        if (dist > maxDist) {
            maxDist = dist;
        }
    }

    // The thresholds for minDist are chosen subjectively
    // based on testing. The unit is not related to pixel
    // distances; it is related to the number of failed tests
    // for similarity between the matched descriptors.
    if (minDist > 50.0) {
        // The target is completely lost.
        // Discard any previously found corners.
        scene_corners.create(0, 0, scene_corners.type());
        return;
    } else if (minDist > 20.0) {
        // The target is lost but maybe it is still close.
        // Keep any previously found corners.
        System.err.println("The target is lost but maybe it is still close. Keep any previously found corners.");
        return;
    }


    // Identify "good" keypoints based on match distance.
    ArrayList<Point> goodReferencePointsList = new ArrayList<Point>();
    ArrayList<Point> goodScenePointsList = new ArrayList<Point>();

    double maxGoodMatchDist = 1.75 * minDist;
    for(DMatch match : matchesList) {
        if (match.distance < maxGoodMatchDist) {
           goodReferencePointsList.add(
                   object_keypoints_list.get(match.queryIdx).pt);
           goodScenePointsList.add(
                   scene_keypoints_list.get(match.trainIdx).pt);
           this.object_good_keypoints.add(object_keypoints_list.get(match.queryIdx));
           this.scene_good_keypoints.add(scene_keypoints_list.get(match.trainIdx));
        }
    }

    if (goodReferencePointsList.size() < 4 ||
            goodScenePointsList.size() < 4) {
        // There are too few good points to find the homography.
        System.err.println("There are too few good points to find the homography.");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Match found");

    MatOfPoint2f goodReferencePoints = new MatOfPoint2f();
    goodReferencePoints.fromList(goodReferencePointsList);

    MatOfPoint2f goodScenePoints = new MatOfPoint2f();
    goodScenePoints.fromList(goodScenePointsList);

    System.out.println("goodReferencePoints size ="+goodReferencePoints.size());
    System.out.println("goodScenePoints size ="+goodScenePoints.size());

    Mat homography = Calib3d.findHomography(goodReferencePoints, goodScenePoints);

    System.out.println("homography = "+homography.dump());

    object_corners = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
    scene_corners = new Mat(4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);

    object_corners.put(0, 0, new double[] { 0, 0 });
    object_corners.put(1, 0, new double[] { object_image.cols(), 0 });
    object_corners.put(2, 0, new double[] { object_image.cols(), object_image.rows() });
    object_corners.put(3, 0, new double[] { 0, object_image.rows() });

    Core.perspectiveTransform(object_corners, scene_corners, homography);

    print_corners();

    Point p0 = new Point(scene_corners.get(0, 0));
    Point p1 = new Point(scene_corners.get(1, 0));
    Point p2 = new Point(scene_corners.get(2, 0));
    Point p3 = new Point(scene_corners.get(3, 0));
    int offset = (int) new Point(object_corners.get(1, 0)).x;

    System.out.println("Matches size = "+matches.size());

    MatOfKeyPoint object_good_kp = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    object_good_kp.fromList(this.object_good_keypoints);
    MatOfKeyPoint scene_good_kp = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    scene_good_kp.fromList(this.scene_good_keypoints);

    System.out.println("object kps = "+this.object_keypoints.size());
    System.out.println("object good kps = "+this.object_good_keypoints.size());
    System.out.println("scene kps = "+this.scene_keypoints.size());
    System.out.println("scene good kps = "+this.scene_good_keypoints.size());

    Features2d.drawMatches(object_image, object_keypoints, scene_image, scene_keypoints, matches, img_matches, new Scalar(255, 0, 0),
            new Scalar(0, 0, 255), new MatOfByte(), 2);

    Core.line(img_matches, new Point(p0.x+offset, p0.y), new Point(p1.x+offset, p1.y), COLOR_GREEN, 4);
    Core.line(img_matches, new Point(p1.x+offset, p1.y), new Point(p2.x+offset, p2.y), COLOR_GREEN, 4);
    Core.line(img_matches, new Point(p2.x+offset, p2.y), new Point(p3.x+offset, p3.y), COLOR_GREEN, 4);
    Core.line(img_matches, new Point(p3.x+offset, p3.y), new Point(p0.x+offset, p0.y), COLOR_GREEN, 4);

    System.out.println(String.format("-- Writing result Mat in %s", pathResult));
    Highgui.imwrite(pathResult, img_matches);

}
```

And here is the terminal output where we can see that the homography matrix has some negative values:

```
Match found
goodReferencePoints size =1x10
goodScenePoints size =1x10
homography = [0.0728467050846091, -1.778341899752422, 523.4269328629535;
  0.05293440263461851, -1.283649810597391, 377.7784434651413;
  0.0001384401936905583, -0.003397194330027168, 1]
-- Object-Point 0 [0,0]
-- Object-Point 1 [259,0]
-- Object-Point 2 [259,878]
-- Object-Point 3 [0,878]
-- Scene-Point 0 [523.43,377.78]
-- Scene-Point 1 [523.52,377.94]
-- Scene-Point 2 [523.45,377.81]
-- Scene-Point 3 [523.5,377.89]
Matches size = 1x2341
object kps = 1x2341
object good kps = 10
scene kps = 1x2576
scene good kps = 10
```

On the picture we can see that the matches are drawn but only one green point is there. It should be the contour in green, not just one point.
And the picture:
[image: On the picture we can see the matches and just one green point which should be the 4 corners...]

Comment: There are other overloads for `findHomography`. [This one](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/calib3d/Calib3d.html#findHomography(org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f,%20int,%20double,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)) in particular allows you to use RANSAC, which should improve your homography results.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what the threshold means? On the Internet there are too complicated explanations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you specify the RANSAC method, the threshold is the maximum reprojection error for considering a point an inlier. In other words, how many pixels away can a "matching" point be if it were projected onto the other image?

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, it has helped a lot.